# Twitter API Media Upload not working

Tags: api, twitter

I am working on Twitter API to create a functionality for the users to tweet directly from the software:
Here is my code:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($this->getTwitterbpTable()->getConsumerKey(), $this->getTwitterbpTable()->getConsumerSecret(), $account->oauth_token , $account->oauth_secret);
$connection->setTimeouts(10, 150);
$media1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => 'https://bleupagereview.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/bleupage.png']);
        $parameters = [
                'status' => 'My Media tweet here',
                'media_ids' => implode(',', [$media1->media_id_string])
        ];

        $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $parameters));
```

The scripts works fine (does not throw any error/exception), but instead of uploading the file, it simply tweets the media id.

How should I change it so that it uploads the media file with status message.

Answer (score 0):

Post function should be like this:

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```